# VLookup multiple items into one cell

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

In Google Sheets, I have a Vlookup working for a column with the thing I'm looking for, then two columns in a different sheet with sheetname! where it looks for the thing I'm looking for and gives me back the ID #. So like...

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,sheetname!A$2:B$19121,2,FALSE)
```

for

```
33270   VNY business name   31199
```

So B2 is what I'm looking for in the sheetname sheet in two columns where one column is the post ID and one column has what's in B2.

For a single value it works great.

But now I have the need to find multiple ids for multiple business codes.

So let's say I have 30 location codes which match up to 1 business ID.
So I have a column for a listing with 30 location codes and on the same row the business ID.

This business ID has 30 locations. I want the ID's of all of the locations to show up in one column. The locations are 3 letter codes which are all in one cell.

So the row/columns look like:
This is what I have to work with:

```
Business Post ID |  Business Location 3 letter code
 12345           |  ABC, XYZ, RFT, PTR, BBC, QRZ
```

In the second sheet is the list of the Business Location 3 letter codes and their Post IDs:

```
Business Location | Business Location POST ID
ABC               | 56789
XYZ               | 37560
RFT               | 25491
PTR               | 89976
BBC               | 44538
QRZ               | 99852
```

The goal is to have a new column which gives me just one cell which tells me all of the business location post IDs for that business Post ID.

So what I want is something that looks like:

```
Business Post ID  |. Business Location Post IDs
12345.             | 56789,37560,99852
```

Right now for the single version which works great I am using

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,sheetname!A$2:B$19121,2,FALSE)
```

in which the sheet is the list of businesses with their post ids and B2 is the column with the business 3 letter code. The second sheet (sheetname) has a column of all 3 letter codes with a second column with that 3 letter code's post id.

Does that make sense? I want to take that theory but have it look up all of the post ids for all of the 3 letter codes in the cell.

The data is being given to me where it's the business post id and a cell with say 70 3 letter code location, each of which have their own Post id in the other sheet/column.

I see this
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2706-excel-vlookup-return-multiple-values-in-one-cell.html
But I'm not sure that it's the right track or quite how to implement.

If anyone can help I'd sure appreciate it!

I tried this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(B2=sheetname!$A$2:$A$1920,$B$2:$B$1920,""))
```

where sheetname A is the business 3 letter code and column B is 3 letter code post ID, but it didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What web app are you using?

Comment: Sorry...Google Sheets, should have said that. I did get a solution from a Reddit poster...
=ARRAYFORMULA(Join(",",VLOOKUP(SPLIT(B2,",",TRUE,TRUE),C:D,2,False)))
if that helps anyone else.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Please post the solution as an answer as comments have less visibility and they are intended for asking/providing some clarification to help making the post more clear / helpful.